# .htaccess file broke my WP site

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess

All I added was server authorization.  I did it on top of the existing WordPress .htaccess stuff I found in there.

The authorization works, great, btw.  But now I get a "500 Internal Server" error.  I'm new to WP and I'm assuming this .htaccess file came standard with the install.  Perhaps it's just something obvious I can't see for some reason?

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthName "PROTECTED ZONE"
require valid-user
Satisfy Any
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devip/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /devip/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you view your apache error.log? internal server errors should be logged in there. Probably some little error in the htaccess file.

Comment: ugh.  I wish.  If you can tell me how to see the logs via shared hosting via Godaddy, I'm all ears.

Comment: Eeeh hate shared hosting. Brought a vps a few years ago to use for a whole bunch of sites and could never go back

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `.htpasswd` exist? It is searched relative to the `ServerRoot`.

[Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html#authuserfile):

> File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute (i.e., if it doesn't begin with a slash), it is treated as **relative to the [ServerRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serverroot)**.

My guess is that it's not sitting in the `ServerRoot` directory on your server. Please check it and correct the path if needed.

Comment: It does exist and the authorization, as I mentioned, works great.  Once, I'm logged in, however, I get the server error.  Can't even serve up a phpinfo.php page!

Comment: @Lynn, But is it in the root directory of the server (ServerRoot, not DocumentRoot)? Because if it isn't it, it'd seem as if the authorization works but in fact, even though the name and password is asked it is not being checked and the server returns 500 (because there's nothing to check against).

Comment: @Lynn, under the other answer you've noted you're on a shared hosting. In that case I'm pretty sure your password file is _not_ in the _server_ root.

Comment: It is because I put it into the root/target_dir directory where I installed WP and a few other things that I was playing around with (not with server side stuff until this htaccess file though).  And when I request the index.php page for that directory, as expected my ,htaccess authorization screen pops up, I enter my user/pass (.htpasswd is stored right at that level) and it logs me in.  But .php files are not being served in that directory.  they are being served in the directory above it....

Comment: I still think you're mixing up _server_ root of the webserver (which you probably _don't_ have access to on a shared hosting) and _document_ root of your site. Take a look in `phpinfo()` (temporarily remove htaccess if you need to get it working) and search for "Server Root" and for "DOCUMENT_ROOT" to see the difference. If you're putting the `.htpasswd` in the root of your website presentation, then take the value of "Server Root" and prepend the `AuthUserFile` directive with it.

Answer (score 0):

500 Server errors sometimes have to do with the character encoding of the .htaccess file. I made that mistake when I first started working with WordPress and .htaccess files.

What kind of text editor did you use to edit .htaccess? With a Windows PC, you should use Notepad and save as plain text. On a Mac, use TextEdit and save as plain text. Or use GoDaddys's file manager and open and save the file.